# Google Docs Viewer in react

Tags: reactjs, google-docs, documentviewer, google-document-viewer

I am trying to use Google Docs Viewer from 'react-google-docs-viewer' to display images, files and videos on my app. The library only gives us this implementation

```
<GoogleDocsViewer
  width="600px"
  height="780px"
  fileUrl="https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/raw/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld.pdf"
/>
```

This isn't working in my application, do I have to sign in or provide some other info? Is there another document viewer library I could use for react v18.2?